# Increase NumPy array items by 1 in Python

Tags: python, numpy

I want to increase all the array items by 1 i.e from `[i,j]` to `[i+1,j+1]`. I have shared the expected output.

```
import numpy as np
I=np.array([[ 0,  2],
       [ 0,  3],
       [ 0,  5],
       [ 1,  6]])
```

The expected output is

```
array([[ 1,  3],
       [ 1,  4],
       [ 1,  6],
       [ 2,  7]])
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try: `I = I + 1` That operation will increment each element